# Overwriting #each; can I pass it args through #map, #select, etc?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I've written my own `Tree` class which includes `Enumerable`. `Tree` then provides an `#each` function. As a consequence, it is able to automatically acquire all the `Enumerable` functions like `#map`, `#select`, `#find`, et cetera. This all works in my code so far.

Here's the problem. When I wrote `#each` for my `Tree`, I gave `#each` an argument which is the name of the tree traversal algorithm to use, such as `:pre_order` or `:breadth_first`. But now when I call `#map` or `#inject` or `#any?` et cetera, it can only use the default traversal algorithm. Is there any way I can pass this argument through the other `Enumerable` functions? Here are my criteria;

- I need to be able to use any traversal algorithm for any `Enumerable` function. This is very important because trees can have very different performance for different algorithms.
- I don't want to rewrite every single `Enumerable` function to pass this argument to `#each`; that defeats the purpose of the module.

Here's an abbreviated version of my code;

```
class Tree
  include Enumerable
  ...

  # Overwrite #each, and give it the algorithm argument.
  def each(algorithm = :pre_order, &block)
    if TRAVERSAL_ALGORITHMS.include? algorithm
      self.send(algorithm, &block)
    else
      self.method_missing(algorithm)
    end
  end

  def pre_order(&block)
    yield self
    self.branches.each do |branch|
      branch.pre_order(&block)
    end
  end

  def post_order(&block)
    ...
  end

  def breadth_first(&block)
    ...
  end

end
```

I want to call things like this;

```
tree.find(13, :breadth_first)
tree.any?(:post_order) do |node|
  node.root >= 10
end
```

Comment: What if instead of passing an argument to each, you had methods for the algorithms which returned Enumerable wrappers of the original tree with each algorithm? E.g. `tree.breadth_first.find(13)` Or is the goal to implement as an argument?

Comment: That's an excellent idea. Can you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so silly.

The method `#enum_for` gives me all the power here. I can implement Charlie's syntax of

```
tree.breadth_first.find(13)
```

by adding the conventional line

```
return self.enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
```

in each of my traversal methods. The `tree.breadth_first` will return an `Enumerator` which enumerates according to the breadth-first algorithm; any `Enumerable` method called on that will use that enumeration internally.

Comment: Ha - totally forgot about enum_for.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: set an instance variable for which algorithm to use. The code would then look like this;

```
class Tree
  include Enumerable
  attr_accessor :traversal_algorithm

  def initialize(...)
    @traversal_algorithm = :pre_order
    ...
  end

  ...

  def each(&block)
    if TRAVERSAL_ALGORITHMS.include? @algorithm
      self.send(@algorithm, &block)
    else
      self.method_missing(@algorithm)
    end
  end

end
```

and the algorithm would be set like this;

```
tree.traversal_algorithm = :breadth_first
tree.find(13)

tree.traversal_algorithm = :post_order
tree.any? do |node|
  node.root >= 10
end
```

This seems like a possibly terrible idea.

Comment: It would make more sense if you make this part of your question, like *"I have come up with this so far, but it seems terrible"*, instead of posting it as an answer to your question. You can edit your question & delete this answer to do that still.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow Charlie's suggestion and use proxy objects:

```
class Tree
  class PreOrderEnumerator
    include Enumerable

    attr_reader :tree

    def initialize(tree)
      @tree = tree
    end

    def each(&block)
      yield tree
      tree.branches.each do |branch|
        branch.pre_order(&block)
      end
    end
  end

  def pre_order
    PreOrderEnumerator.new(self)
  end
end
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
tree.pre_order.any? {|node| node.root > 10 }
```